# ggmap: Using client ID and signature in API calls?

Tags: r, ggmap, google-maps-static-api

How can I use the get_googlemap() function from the ggmap package as a premium plan customer who uses Client ID authentication?

First I "register" my google account details as below

```
register_google(account_type = "premium",
                client = "my-company",
                signature = "my1company1signature")
```

I then run the get_googlemap() function as shown below

```
get_googlemap(center = c(-79,  43))
```

Yielding the error message

```
Error: Google now requires an API key.
   See ?register_google for details.
```

However, I know that I should be able to access the API with just my client ID and signature. Is this functionality available in the package?

Note: I am currently using ggmap 3.0.0. In previous versions (2.7 I think) I did not receive this error message but instead had another issue where the signature was simply attached to the end of the url instead of using the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#dig-sig-key)

Comment: You need to use `register_google(key = "[your key]")` where "[your key]" is the API key value.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

Comment: To clarify - I don't have an API key, I use an alternate authentication method for premium users which uses client ID authentication. This is what I was trying to describe in the first sentence of my post, detail also available in the link at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I understood, your statement, ggmap works with an API key.  You most likely need to log into the google account to generate the API to use.